# Como ordenar pelo menor numero minha tabela com dado que vem de uma api

Tags: php

Como ordenar pelo menor número minha tabela com dado que vem de uma api?

```
<?php   
$query = $mysqladv->query("SELECT * FROM advogados_aux WHERE adv_idunico='$idadvun';");
        while($row = $query->fetch_array()){    

    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$row['adv_cep']."&destinations=".$c_cep."&language=pt&mode=car&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);  


    $distancia = $json_data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']; 
    ?>
```

Comment: ORDER BY variável ASC ou DESC no final da query não funciona?
Que variável queres ordenar?

Comment: Quero ordenar pela $distancia

Comment: ORDER BY distance ASC ou DESC não funciona?

Comment: esse dado nao esta vindo do banco de dados! ai não sei como fazer!